# MongoDB filter with aggegation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDb document in this format

```
{
   account_key : "tiziano",
   notifications : [
       { address: "tiziano@myemail.com" , notification_type: ['booking_confirmation','booking_deletion'] },
       { address: "tiziano@youremail.com" , notification_type: ['booking_confirmation'] },
       { address: "tiziano@yxyzEmail.com" , notification_type: ['credit_card_expiration'] },
   ]
}
```

and the collection contains n documents in this form.
I'm trying to get all the documents that have one specific account_key, and for each documents that matches the search i'd like to have back notification_type that matches a specific criteria. For example i'd like to have back all notifications that have notification_type booking_confirmation

```
    {
        account_key: "tiziano",
        notifications : [
            { address: "tiziano@myemail.com" , notification_type: ['booking_confirmation','booking_deletion'] },
            { address: "tiziano@youremail.com" , notification_type: ['booking_confirmation'] }
        ]
    }
```

This is the query i'm using but it doesn't return what i want

```
db.getCollection("accounts").aggregate([
    { $match : { account_key : "acme" }},
    { $project : {
        notification_contact: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$notifications",
                as: "notification",
                cond: {  $eq : ["$$notification.notification_type", "booking_created"] }
            }
        } 
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to check whether the array contains specific element.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "account_key": "tiziano" } },
  { "$project": {
    "notification_contact": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$notifications",
        "as": "notification",
        "cond": {
          "$in": [
            "booking_confirmation",
            "$$notification.notification_type"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X--qfi_HMmd)